# Create sublist of a list containing tuples and list with starting and end elements of sublist as tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a list for example like this

```
[(1.0, 1.5), [2, 2], (1.5, 1.0), (1.1428571343421936, 0.28571426868438721), [1, 0], (0.5, 0.0), (0.66666668653488159, 0.0), [0, 0], [0, 1], (0.5, 1.25)]
```

I want to create sublists by appending tuple elements as first and last element of sublist, something like this:

```
[[(1.0, 1.5), [2, 2], (1.5, 1.0)],[(1.1428571343421936,
0.28571426868438721), [1, 0], (0.5, 0.0)],[(0.66666668653488159, 0.0), [0, 0], [0, 1], (0.5, 1.25)]]
```

I tried using the following code but it seems not to be working because I am not able to figure out how to chose tuples in the fashion in which I want. Also it gives index error.

```
full_list = []
for ind,value in enumerate(flat_list):
    if isinstance(value,(tuple)):
        a = []
        a.append(value)
        temp = 0
        while(temp!=1):
            ind = ind + 1
            j = flat_list[ind]
            a.append(j)
            if type(j) == 'tuple':
                temp = 1
            break
        full_list.append(a)
    else:
        continue

print(full_list)
```

Please suggest some suggestions !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` as last statement of a `while`-loop can be substituted by `if`.

```
full_list = []
state = 0
for value in flat_list:
    if isinstance(value, tuple):
        if state == 0:
            state = 1
            inner_list = []
            full_list.append(inner_list)
        else:
            state = 0
    inner_list.append(value)

print(full_list)
```